# Present simple grammar

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

When we talk about a lot of animals we use they or it? 
Ex: The three goats( want or wants ) to cross the bridge.

Comment: These three goats, they want the same things that three humans want.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13950/

Comment: *it* is always singular; *they* is always plural.  But it doesn't matter whether you're talking about animals or humans or objects or anything: plural is always *they*.

Answer (score 1):

For a group of anything you need to use the term for "they" unless you are treating the group as a single item. For example:

> The pens need new lids

We use **need** because we have multiple pens, which is clear from the plural in pen**s**.

However, when looking at groups we have two options:

> The family want a new car

Is correct because **the family** is a group of people and therefore is plural. But it is also correct to say:

> The family wants a new car

Because **the family** can also be seen as one *individual* group, and the item itself is not pluralised. For example if we then changed it to **families** we would need to revert back to "want".